# Neo4j relationship writing process

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I am using Neo4j graph to create graph database. using load csv command to create relationship. It takes 2hours to load 1 million data rows relationship into any relationship. Is there any other way to create relationship faster?

Comment: Can you share your cypher load csv query ? Have you created somes indexes / constraints ?

Comment: q='''USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///raw.csv" AS row
MATCH (tweet_id:tweet_id {name: row.tweet_id})
MATCH (indexed_date:indexed_date {name: row.indexed_date})
MERGE (indexed_date)-[date_i_tweet:date_i_tweet]->(tweet_id);'''
graph_3.cypher.execute(q)

Comment: i have created indexes on tweet_id

Answer (score 1):

CREATE is faster than MERGE.And using MERGE or MATCH can result 'Eager Operation'. Please go through this [blog](http://blog.bruggen.com/2015/07/loading-belgian-corporate-registry-into_20.html) for more reference.

As a work around you can try the below query.

You can use WITH in the query for avoinding cartisian product and whole 'row' to pass down. Try adding index to "indexed_date" and try the below query.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///raw.csv" AS row 
MATCH (tweet_id:tweet_id {name: row.tweet_id}) with tweet_id
MATCH (indexed_date:indexed_date {name: row.indexed_date}) with indexed_date,tweet_id
CREATE (indexed_date)-[date_i_tweet:date_i_tweet]->(tweet_id);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this helps.Just a question. Have you worked on real time update on neo4j. As the data size increases the updation process is lower. Any suggestion on updating the garph faster?

Comment: yes the updation is slow. try limiting the data or focus on one set of properties/nodes at a time. The update's speed depend on your schema too.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you should have :

- a unique constraint on `tweet_id` : `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:tweet_id) ASSETS n.tweet_id IS UNIQUE`
- a unique constraint or an `indexed_date` : `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:indexed_date) ASSETS n.indexed_date IS UNIQUE`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks everyone. This helps.